# I've updated my art assets, but Xcode is still using old files

Tags: xcode, file-management

I have a cocos2d game project. I have a bunch of pvr, png, plist files in a directory called Graphics/iPhone (for iPhone) and Graphics/iPad (for iPad). The directories are folder references, and not groups. I'm not using svn, but use Dropbox to keep data backed up.

I updated some of my PNG files with some modifications using Photoshop, but Xcode still uses old art assets from the previous build. Here's what I have tried:

1. Product > Clean. Doesn't do anything.
2. Removed the entire Graphics directory from the project. Wow, it still runs! How can it still run when I've removed all the graphics? Anyhow, I added them back. Still no go.
3. Uninstalled the app on my iPad. While it DOES work for Simulator and I can see the updated art assets, it doesn't work on my iPad.
4. Restarted Xcode. Doesn't solve anything.

Can anybody give me some pointers on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean, the resources files are reference to dropbox?

I would try to, at least, keep them local while developing, I believe dropbox has some sore of caching algorithm that keeps them from accessing from different sources. (I know that you might see the new images by opening dropbox directly, but again, it is just a guess and I would try that)

I had some similar before, and I did everything you did plus removing cocos2d and adding again, and worked fine.

good luck, I know how it is annoying

Comment: The resources are all local. The project is in the "My Dropbox" directory and keeps getting backed up.
What I fail to understand is that how can everything still work when I've deleted all the graphics.

Answer (score 0):

To update all art assets for your build, you must:

1. In Xcode go to Product > Clean Build Folder...
2. Then Delete the app from your iphone device.

After performing these two steps, old art assets that had been deleted were no longer used in the build.